# How Linear SVM Regression and Multiple Linear Regression different in terms of the regression result?

Tags: linear-regression, svm

They starts from the same equation as below.

y = w*x + b

But they solve it differently. MLR specified the w and b by minimizing the square error whereas SVM specified w and b by minimizing the loss function defined by C and epsilon.

I am wondering if the result of regression is significantly different. I guess that if the given data set is clean and well-explained by input features, the resultant w and b between SVM and MLR will be close. Putting my original question differently, I don't find any reasons to use linear SVM regression over multiple linear regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They could potentially be very different, because linear regression penalizes using *squared* error while SVRs penalize *absolute* error. You might have learned that "outliers" can have an outsized influence on the regression line because of this--this won't be the case with SVR, however.

Furthermore, if the SVR you're talking about is like the one described [here](https://alex.smola.org/papers/2003/SmoSch03b.pdf) (great resource there, by the way) then choosing a larger $\epsilon$ will yield a flatter regression line/hyperplane, whereas you don't have such a tuning parameter for regular ol' linear regression. This parameter enables you to try to fight overfitting by flattening the regression line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think the difference is significant only when the weight of outliers or noise is not negligible. (That's why why I said "when the given data set is clean"). but in that case, isn't it much better and robust using noise filters before applying MLR in terms of implementation time&efforts vs performance?  Also, is there any way to quantitatively compare the quality of these two regressions? The result reported by CV-RMSE or r2 would be disadvantageous to SVR because it is MLR that is wired in a to minimize such a reported error regardless of the quality of regression.

Comment: Remember, what you really care about in the end is predictiveness on a test set. A noise filter might give you "cleaner" data but might hurt you on test set accuracy! The gold standard of comparison is examining the empirical losses of the models on a test set. If you care more about L1 loss than L2 loss, validate on L1 loss. The loss function of the model is just a means for fitting the model. It's even possible that linear regression will perform worse in test RMSE because it's overfitted!